# Looping from a start date to an end date

Tags: php, date, loops

I'd like to make a **selection list of dates** that a user could choose from. The date should start by the **Current date today** and ends **5 days after**. I just don't know how to execute it inside a loop so I wouldn't change the date over and over again. Thanks. Please help.

Comment: That depends pretty much on which programming language your are using.

Comment: its PHP. Sorry forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the php DateTime functions for this:

```
<?php

    $date = new DateTime();    // Without argument: now
    $interval = new Dateinterval("P1D"); // Period: 1 day
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++) {
       echo $date->format("Y-m-d")."\n";
       $date->add($interval);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $today = date('d/m/y');
    for($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
          $nextDay = date('m/d/y', time() + (86400*$i));
          //make something with your date
    }
?>
```

Do you mean something like this?

Comment: No. It is adding to the days. `24(h)*60(min)*60(sec) = 86400`. I changed formatting, check it now. In Polish notation days comes first, not months. I have forgotten about this detail.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<select name=\"date\">\n";
for($i=time();$i<time()+5*24*60*60;$i+=24*60*60) {
    $d = date('Y-m-d', $i);
    echo echo "<option value=\"$d\">$d</option>\n";
}
echo "</select>\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty way:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++){
    print date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d') + $i, date('Y')));
    print "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UNIX timestamp to store the time and loop.

Use `date('Y-m-d', $timestamp)` to generate a string of date.

Use `strtotime($string)` to convert a Y-m-d string to timestamp integer.

```
$now = time();
for($i = $now; $i < $now + 5*86400; $i=$i+86400)
{
    $Ymd = date('Y-m-d', $i);
    //do other things here.
}
```